# Silverlight deployment data provider missing

Tags: silverlight, provider

I am deploying a silverlight application which uses a mysql db through ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

When trying to run the application from my host, the WCF service works fine, but I get a server exception when calling from wcf service:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString).

My code in web.config is defined as follows

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="modelEntities"  
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=userid;password=mypass;database=mydb;&quot;"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

On my local project it works fine, as I have installed the .NET Connector for mysql, etc.
The host supports .net 3.5 linq and mysql.
What do I need to do to fix this?

---

I have tried adding

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

and MySql.Data.dll and MySql.Data.Entity.dll in the bin folder and now i am getting the error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors:     
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.1.ssdl(4,9) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '5' is different from '5.1' that was encountered earlier.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(4,9) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '5' is different from '5.1' that was encountered earlier.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(7,4) : error 0019: The EntityContainer name must be unique. An EntityContainer with the name 'Schema' is already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(336,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.Table' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(348,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.TableColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(374,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.View' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(386,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ViewColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(412,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.Function' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(437,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.Procedure' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(447,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.Parameter' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(471,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.Constraint' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(483,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.CheckConstraint' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(491,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ConstraintColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(500,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ForeignKeyConstraint' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(509,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ForeignKey' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(520,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ViewConstraint' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(535,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.TableTableConstraint' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(548,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ConstraintConstraintColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(561,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ConstraintForeignKey' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(574,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.FromForeignKeyColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(587,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ToForeignKeyColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(600,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.TableTableColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(613,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ViewViewColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(626,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.FunctionFunctionParameter' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(639,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ProcedureProcedureParameter' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(652,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ViewViewConstraint' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(665,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ViewConstraintConstraintColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(678,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ViewConstraintForeignKey' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(691,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.FromForeignKeyViewColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-5.0.ssdl(704,4) : error 0019: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'MySqlClient.ToForeignKeyViewColumn' was already defined.    
MySql.Data.Entity.Properties.SchemaDefinition-6.0.ssdl(4,9) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '5' is different from '5.1' that was encountered earlier.
```

What's this? Why is it so hard to deploy this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding an explicit reference to MySql.Data, then on your hosting account ensure the a copy of MySql.Data.dll is included in your bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember. You cannot have two entity models using different databases in the same project. It seems like you also have a sql server or other db entity model or something referring to sql server which isnt clean.

Try with only one entity model with mysql only.

Comment: thats the odd thing. i do not have two entity models. i have created only one. i have no idea why it gets confused. i have one entity model in mysql database. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you point the Entity framework to some db first and then shifted to mysql?

Seems like somebody has similar problem

[click here to see the error & solution that worked for him](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,280149,280149#msg-280149)